# subscribe one variable from big topic msg

Tags: ros, pid, message, namespace, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using PID pkg that requires a std_msgs float type from topic but I am publishing this variable from a big topic that is the state of the plant (has several floats, integers and booleans)

When I try to subscribe to the variable, a new topic appears with the same namespace but without data.

For example:

The velocity is publishing inside `movement_manager/velocity` which is a custom msg called: StatusPlant.msg with `movement_manager/status`, `movement_manager/config` , etc.

I want to link the PID float message subscribed from `movement_manager` topic in order to do the PID controller but without luck.

The way I am doing it is with a parameter in a launchfile:

```
<node name="pid_controller" pkg="pid" type="controller" output="screen">
  <param name="state_topic" value="movement_manager/velocity"/>
  ...
</node>
```

I tried with remap too but nothing changed.

Anybody knows the way to do it without publishing again the same velocity in a separate float message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232748/subscribe-one-variable-from-big-topic-msg/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2016-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That would be a nice feature, though there could be ambiguous cases with the same names  (it could always default to the actual topic which it looks like rostopic echo does, unless it doesn't match the expected type then try the message field), or some other character than `/` could be required.

[topic_tools transform](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform) can relay message fields:

```
rostopic pub /test geometry_msgs/Point "{x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0}" -r 1
```

Then

```
rosrun topic_tools transform /test /test/z std_msgs/Float64 'm.z'
```

This is neat:

```
rosrun topic_tools transform /test /test/xy opencv_apps/Point2D 'm.x, m.y'
```

or

```
rostopic pub /test sensor_msgs/Image "{header: auto, height: 0, width: 0, encoding: '', is_bigendian: 0, step: 0, data: ''}"  -r 1

rosrun topic_tools transform /test /test/header std_msgs/Header 'm.header'
```

and then `test/z`, `test/xy`, or `test/header` exist for any node that wants them.

If ros could do it automatically ideally it would not do it in the subscriber (requiring the overhead of transporting and receiving an entire Image for example just for a few bytes of a field), but would be essentially launching something like the topic_tools transform behind the scenes.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2016-04-25**:
Thak works properly. Thanks. The way I did it is by roslaunch:

```
<node name="publish_velocity" pkg="topic_tools" type="transform"
args="/movement_manager/status_info /movement_manager/velocity std_msgs/Float64 m.trc.velocity" />
```

**Comment by [samarth.robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39083/samarth.robo/) on 2019-12-19**:
Those who got the error `ERROR: Wrong input topic (or topic field):`, please be aware of a [namespace bug](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1427) in `transform`.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-10-11**:
The namespace bug has been fixed, but there is another issue with transform that appears only the first time transform is run for a given roscore session #q349655

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot subscribe to part of a message. The publisher and subscriber types must match, and you have to subscribe to the whole topic.

(rostopic echo and rqt_plot make it seems like you can subscribe to one field, but they're actually subscribing to the entire message and only printing part of it. This is the exception; very few other parts of ROS can do this.)

If you have a subscriber that accepts a particular topic type, you must publish a topic with that type. That might mean modifying your existing publisher to publish a second topic, or writing a very small relay node which subscribes to the entire topic and republishes on a new topic with the desired type and data.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3